# dired: how to get really human readable output (find-ls-option)

Tags: emacs, dired

I am looking for human readable output for `M-x find-dired`/`M-x find-gred-dired`. I tried to use the following:

```
(setq find-ls-option '("-print0 | xargs -0 ls -alhd" . "-alhd"))
```

However, due to the `-h`, the found output is not properly aligned anymore and so not really human readable (see the screenshot below [dired+]). Is there a (not-too-intrusive) solution for this?

[image]

As artscan pointed out, `-i` is an option. I then found this "counterexample":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit around. The indent was suddenly fine except for the files which have file sizes given in bytes (so without a unit). I then was wondering what the "second" set of options in `find-ls-option` is about. Although `C-h v find-ls-option` does not explain it in a clear way (IMHO), I found that just leaving the second set of options empty provides the correct indent:

```
(setq find-ls-option '("-print0 | xargs -0 ls -alhd" . ""))
```

Comment: Second argument is for manually changes of `dired-buffer`, e.g. by `wdired-mode`. It isn't work for me with any setup: even with  option `(setq find-ls-option '("-print0 | xargs -0 ls -alhd" . "-alhd"))` after exiting from `wdired-mode` you get incorrect output. Also if second option is `""`.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example when `wdired-mode` fails? I just tried,  it worked for the case I considered without flaws with the solution I provided above. It might be a quick hack (which does it for me at the moment -- patching .el files might be dangerous, too). I guess a developer should look into this -- after all, human-readable output is one of the "selling points" of dired+, so it should work :-)

Comment: Minimal example when `wdired-mode` fails: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1897885/example.png Yes, I think about it - try to send the patch.

Comment: Ahh... I got the same as you in my original small test case. In the end I saw the whole directory without formatting. I just quitted and went to the directory in "normal" dired mode. The file was properly changed (so it seems to work apart from this "side-effect"). 

      It would be great if you could send a proper patch, artscan. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Problem is in regex. You have to patch function `find-dired-filter`:

```
diff -u -L /usr/share/emacs/24.2/lisp/find-dired.el.gz -L \#\<buffer\ find-dired.el.gz\> /tmp/jka-com8644f_j /tmp/buffer-content-86445Tw
--- /usr/share/emacs/24.2/lisp/find-dired.el.gz
+++ #<buffer find-dired.el.gz>
@@ -289,7 +289,7 @@
            (l-opt (and (consp find-ls-option)
                (string-match "l" (cdr find-ls-option))))
            (ls-regexp (concat "^ +[^ \t\r\n]+\\( +[^ \t\r\n]+\\) +"
-                      "[^ \t\r\n]+ +[^ \t\r\n]+\\( +[0-9]+\\)")))
+                      "[^ \t\r\n]+ +[^ \t\r\n]+\\( +[0-9,.]+\\)")))
        (goto-char beg)
        (insert string)
        (goto-char beg)
```

Comment: Hi artscan, thanks for helping. Please see my update. `-i` already does a good job, but I found a "counterexample" when it fails to align the files properly. (Also, the index number I don't really need).

Comment: Another way is removing comma (or dot) and decimal part from column "size" in `ls -lh` output

Comment: Hi artscan. I tried to put in your patch, but this a) did not work and b) seems quite intrusive. I post a solution below.